# How do i reference a popup form in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

When I click on a button that creates a popup form, my VBA code `Screen.ActiveForm` still references the form containing the popup button, even when the popup form has focus. How do I reference the popup form in this case? So confused why Access doesn't register the popup with focus as the active form...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Forms` collection which lists all open forms

```
Forms!MyPopup
```

or, if you have invalid characters in the name of the form

```
Forms![My Popup]
```

or

```
Forms("My Popup")
```

---

You can access controls on it with

```
Forms![My Popup]!TextBox1
```

Comment: This works... but I am also trying to get the name of the active control without having to type its literal name. Forms("my popup").ActiveControl.Name gives `Run-time error 2474: The expression you entered requires the control to be in the active window` as soon as the popup appears (I have the code in the `Form_BeforeUpdate` event.

Comment: Set the focus to the form with `Forms![My Popup].SetFocus` before you get the active control.

Comment: I get the same error with the code `Forms("TaskBasic").SetFocus` newline `Debug.Print Forms("TaskBasic").ActiveControl.Name`

Comment: New info: I get that same error message, but it does actually output the name of the correct control... should I simply ignore the error message or it is possibly going to bite me in the butt later?

Comment: You might have an issue with the `Form_BeforeUpdate` event handler still running. You could go the other way round and put the code in the popup form into the control AfterUpdate and send the value to the main form: `Forms!MainForm!TextBox1.Value = Me!TextBoxInThePopUp.Value`

Comment: I can't do that because I need a dynamic reference to the active control since there are so many. But thanks for the help. The same error comes up in the `AfterUpdate` event. Not sure why Access makes it impossible to  reference the active control in an active popup... thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting this error. I made a test and don't get it - even when the popup isn't active. Are you sure that this is the statement causing the error?

Comment: Hmm odd... yes the `debug.print` is the highlighted statement when I go to the debugger.

Comment: `ActiveForm` and `ActiveControl` do not work from the Immediate window, because the Immediate window takes away the focus from Access Forms and Controls!

Answer (score 0):

when opening/creating the pop-up form, store the form name in a variable, then reference that variable when required.

```
dim sPopup$

sPopup="FRM_Popup"

docmd.openform sPopup

...reference popup form here using sPopup...
```